# AD Site Name not being applied to some servers

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have seen multiple servers/workstations in our AD that are in `gpresult /R` show Site Name: N/A even thou their `subnet` is defined in `Active Directory Sites and Services`. What could be the reason for that? Where to look for possible failure. Because of this some stuff like detecting Exchange server in same `subnet` doesn't work. Replication seems to work fine.

```
C:\Users\admin>nltest /dsgetsite
Katowice-Kolokacja
The command completed successfully

C:\Users\admin>nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com /Account:KOLCENTRAL$
           DC: \\AD7.domain.com
      Address: \\172.16.50.7
     Dom Guid: 2d9bd8bc-3124-44ca-b2cb-960159dd75e2
     Dom Name: domain.com
  Forest Name: domain.com
 Dc Site Name: Katowice-Kolokacja
Our Site Name: Katowice-Kolokacja
        Flags: GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV WRITABLE DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FOREST CLO
SE_SITE FULL_SECRET WS 0x4000
The command completed successfully


C:\Users\admin>gpresult /R

Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-2001

Created On 3/18/2013 at 10:00:00 PM


RSOP data for DOMAIN\admin on KOLCENTRAL : Logging Mode
------------------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Member Server
OS Version:                  6.1.7601
Site Name:                   N/A
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\admin
Connected over a slow link?: No
```

Ip address

```
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.50.200(Preferred)
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.50.254

 DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.50.7
                                     172.16.50.8
```

Sites and Services:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share with us the output of `nltest /dsgetsite` and `nltest /dsgetdc:your.domain.com /Account:BustedPC01$` from one of the affected PCs.

Comment: updated question with information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a display problem. Your Sites & Subnets are fine. The client knows to which site it belongs, as evidenced by the nltest output. My Windows 7 client here shows N/A in gpresult /R as well.

gpresult /R when run from an un-elevated command prompt only shows data for the user, and the user doesn't really have a "Site" in the same sense that the computer does. The user inherits her locality from the computer she logs on to.

Run gpresult /R from an elevated command prompt and you should see Computer settings as well, which will show you the proper site name. And the user section won't even have a Site Name property listed any more.

I say the source of your Exchange problems lie somewhere else...

Comment: You are right. After elevating it shows proper site. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that the subnet masks in AD Sites and Services are correct. I ran in to this problem once where the subnet masks on were 255.255.0.0 on the client machines but AD had /24's defined.

Comment: It doesn't seems so. Check updated question